# Writing to output the same time the user is writing

Tags: c, linux

I want to write to the terminal at the same time the user is inputting a command for my program. For example, when the user is trying to print 'help', it could end up looking like this:

```
heNew packet with length 233
lp
```

I'd like to be able to have command input just below where everything is outputted, so it would look something like this:

```
New packet with length 223
Sending x to y..
...
>help
```

I want to avoid using a library for this. The program is not cross-platform so a linux-only solution would work.

Comment: How does the user input?

Comment: You really should look for ncurses,  they are a library, but they'll take care of everything with minimal effort: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will require that you manage the raw input and output to the screen.  You say that you don't want to use a library but I would strongly encourage you to have a look at ncurses.  If you really want to build this from scratch you will be reinventing lots of wheels. :)

Comment: I think ncurses should be able to help, but how do I put the input bar at the bottom of the screen? I want to be able to use select() because it's reading from a network socket at the same time.

Comment: You will need to use asynchronous network connections with your select so that you can do other things in your event loop when there is no data pending.  Take a look at the IO select calls.  Ncurses will allow you to put anything anywhere that you want on the screen.

Comment: I am using asynchronous network connections, but I want to be able to input commands in the program at the bottom of the screen. I can input commands by using select on stdin (0), but I can't see what I'm typing.

Comment: You will have to put the characters out onto the screen where you want them.